# OData as query serialization syntax

Tags: c#, linq, odata, expression-trees

I'm trying to modernize a pre-existing C# data-access framework, and migrating to OData sounds like a reasonable end-goal. However, a big-bang conversion seems unlikely to succeed; I'd prefer to use just parts of OData at first - in particular just the query syntax.

**Edit:** to be clear, queries are not currently transported via a REST like interface (and though HTTP is involved, it's only indirectly used; queries and results are transported in larger bundles with lots of other data), so using web api and the "behind the scenes" conversion it provides is not an option.

Given a type `TEntity` and a LINQ expression tree `filter` that could serve as the argument to a `Queryable.Where<TEntity>(source, filter)`, how can I generate the query that an OData client would send in the OData `$filter` clause?  And the other way around: how can I parse that `$filter` clause back into an expression tree?  OData libraries must already do this behind the scenes, but I don't know where to look for the right code.

Mild variations on this theme would work for me too; e.g. if it's simpler to generate not just the $filter clause but a complete (but fake) request, that's fine too - as long as there's no actual HTTP requests made by the client, and no query execution by the server.  I'd prefer to migrate to the latest version (v4), but it's not a requirement.

In essence: is it possible to use OData as a query (de)serializer?

Comment: You could probably write any custom library to do what you want, but the question is why? Microsoft gives you a full blown ODataQueryOptions object. So you can simply accept this as a parameter to your action (method). The webapi model binder then converts all parts of standard odata convention into this object which you can simply .ApplyTo() your IQueryable<T>. Also, if you're using DTO's you're able to manually convert parts of the query as strings. This is the biggest benefit for using OData in c# web projects - you do not have to write the framework, MS did that for you.

Comment: The data currently does not arrive via HTTP; nor does this project use Web api at all at it's unlikely to be able too any time soon.  What you're suggesting is quite a complex undertaking - it means I can't change just the filter syntax, but need to change the entire chain at once, *and* need to invert control flow (instead of app code calling library code, it would be framework code calling app code), *and* need to change the network architecture to use web api's preferred http transport.

Comment: you can still take a string, wrap it into HttpRequestMessage and ODataQueryContext and convert it into ODataQueryOptions<T>. The model binding is a convenience and transport is really not an issue for OData. Although that said, OData is designed for HTTP RESTful querying, thus it handles the limitations and problems of that protocol particularly well; the same may not be correct for other transport methods.

Comment: Yes, you can change just the filter syntax, you will simply supply all of the original Odata requests back. In our app to separate concerns we simply accept ODataQueryOptions<T>? down to the repository layer and .ApplyTo if not null. There is some tight coupling due to how Microsoft did their framework; you can of course build a wrapper interface and pass that along instead.

Comment: @zaitsman it sounds like you might want to post an answer :-)